# How can form changes be better controlled using ngDoCheck or valueChanges?

Tags: angular, forms, angular-forms

I have a form divided into small components, which in total have over 100 input fields. I need to detect when at least one value is modified and check if the overall form status is **VALID**.

So, currently, I'm using **ngDoCheck**, but is this the correct approach? It works as expected, but would **valueChanges** be more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ControlContainer to link all forms and then simply subscribe to validity changes or value changes of the top level form.

Answer (score 0):

ngDoCheck() is not directly related to this, but it will work. Although, if you'll make some change inside ngDoCheck(), you'll cause infinite loop.

It's better to use valueChanges and [statusChanges](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#statusChanges) - this way you can easily add `debounceTime()`, `distinctUntilChanged()` to improve performance.